# Please why can't I install xampp on my Macbook air

Tags: xampp-vm

I tried to install xampp on my mac but unfortunately, the system said that the xampp can't be opened because it can't be checked for malware. I tried going through system preferences to security and privacy, where I granted the system access to open xampp and install it but still it was unable to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

First, run the App like you did before.

Then open the `Privacy and Security` center and scroll down to the `Security` section. There you should see the blocked app, click `Open anyway`.